# Setting Scroll View's zoomScale and hitting back button crashes program

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller, exc-bad-access

I was trying to make a program where you click an image and it segues to show it on full screen, scaled so that there is no whitespace around (CS 193P assignment 4 task 7 for anyone who knows it). View controllers are embedded in navigation controller. It turns out that the program crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = EXC_I386_GPFLT)` when I hit the back button in the navigation bar.

I found out that I can prevent this crash by scrolling to the top of the image and then going back. Another way to completely prevent it is to comment out the line that sets scrollView's zoomScale. Here's the code I used for loading and handling the image:

```
import UIKit

class ImageViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView! {
        didSet {
            scrollView.contentSize = imageView.frame.size
            scrollView.delegate = self
            scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.03
            scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 5.0
        }
    }

    func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return imageView
    }

    var imageURL: NSURL? {
        didSet {
            image = nil
            if view.window != nil {
                fetchImage()
            }
        }
    }

    private func fetchImage() {
        if let url = imageURL {
            let qos = Int(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED.value)
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(qos, 0)) {
                let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    if url == self.imageURL {
                        if imageData != nil {
                            self.image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                        } else {
                            self.image = nil
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private var imageView = UIImageView()

    private var image: UIImage? {
        get { return imageView.image }
        set {
            imageView.image = newValue
            imageView.sizeToFit()
            scrollView?.contentSize = imageView.frame.size
            scrollViewDidScrollOrZoom = false
            autoScale()
        }
    }

    private var scrollViewDidScrollOrZoom = false

    private func autoScale() {
        if scrollViewDidScrollOrZoom {
            return
        }
        if let sv = scrollView {
            if image != nil {
                sv.zoomScale = max(sv.bounds.size.width / image!.size.width, sv.bounds.size.height / image!.size.height)
                sv.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: (imageView.frame.size.width - sv.frame.size.width) / 2, y: (imageView.frame.size.height - sv.frame.size.height) / 2)
                scrollViewDidScrollOrZoom = false
            }
        }
    }


    func scrollViewDidEndZooming(scrollView: UIScrollView, withView view: UIView!, atScale scale: CGFloat) {
        scrollViewDidScrollOrZoom = true
    }

    func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        scrollViewDidScrollOrZoom = true
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        if image == nil {
            fetchImage()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        autoScale()
    }
}
```

I tried to make a simple application which segues into ImageViewController from a View Controller that has only a button and is embedded in navigation controller, and the crash is still the same. Here's the code I used in the first view controller:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    let url = NSURL(string: "https://developer.apple.com/swift/images/swift-og.png")

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "Show Full Image" {
            let ivc = segue.destinationViewController as! ImageViewController
            ivc.imageURL = url
        }
    }
}
```

What causes this and am I doing something wrong here? I'm using Xcode 6.3 beta 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem is actually with the scrollView's delegate, as I was able to fix this with adding

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    scrollView.delegate = nil
}
```